# Python : How to access file from different directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, python-import, pythonpath

I have the following project structure

```
SampleProject
     com
       python
          example
             source
                utils
                   ConfigManager.py
     conf
        constants.cfg
```

How to access constants.cfg from ConfigManager.py.

I have a limitation

1. I can not give full path(absolute path) of constants.cfg because if I run in different PC it should work with out any modification
2. Also if I represent something like below, I can access the file. But I don't want to give back slash every time

   ```
   filename = ..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\constants.cfg`
   ```

Currently I am doing something like this. But this works only when constants.cfg and ConfigManager.py are in same directory

```
currentDir =  os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
file = open(os.path.join(currentDir,'constants.cfg'))
```

Comment: I don't know if there's a way around this but to get the current directory, you can use os.getcwd().

Comment: Does SamplePoject contain an \__init__.py file? And does constants.cfg be in a specific format, or could it also be a Python file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `conf` is a Python package then you could use [`pkgutil.get_data()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html):

```
import pkgutil

data = pkgutil.get_data("conf", "constants.cfg")
```

Or if `setuptools` is installed – [`pkg_resources.resource_string()`](http://packages.python.org/distribute/pkg_resources.html#basic-resource-access):

```
import pkg_resources

data = pkg_resources.resource_string('conf', 'constants.cfg')
```

---

If `constants.cfg` is not in a package then pass its path as a command-line parameter, or set it in an environment variable e.g., `CONFIG_MANAGER_CONSTANTS_PATH`, or read from a fixed set of default paths e.g., `os.path.expanduser("~/.config/ConfigManager/constants.cfg")`. To find a place where to put user data, you could use [`appdirs` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/appdirs).

You can't use `os.getcwd()` that returns current working directory if you may run `ConfigManager.py` from different directories. Relative path `"../../..."` won't work for the same reason.

If you are certain that the relative position of `ConfigManager.py` and `constants.cfg` in the filesystem won't change:

```
import inspect
import os
import sys

def get_my_path():
    try:
        filename = __file__ # where we were when the module was loaded
    except NameError: # fallback
        filename = inspect.getsourcefile(get_my_path)
    return os.path.realpath(filename)

# path to ConfigManager.py
cm_path = get_my_path()
# go 6 directory levels up
sp_path = reduce(lambda x, f: f(x), [os.path.dirname]*6, cm_path)
constants_path = os.path.join(sp_path, "conf", "constants.cfg")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had some module in the root of the project tree, say config_loader.py that looked like this:

```
import os

def get_config_path():
    relative_path = 'conf/constants.cfg'
    current_dir = os.getcwd()
    return os.join(current_dir, relative_path)
```

And then in ConfigManager.py or any other module that needs the configs:

```
import config_loader

file_path = config_loader.get_config_path()
config_file = open(file_path)
```

You could even have your config_loader.py just return the config file.

Comment: `getcwd()` would work only if you run ConfigManager.py from SampleProject directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **pathlib** package in **Python 3.0+**

This gets the path to any file contained in the **SampleProject** folder
across different **platforms**.

```
from pathlib import Path
def get_file(path):
    """
    returns the absolute path of a file
    :var
    str path
        the file path within the working dir
    :returns
    PureWindowsPath or PurePosixPath object
        type depends on the operating system in use
    """
    def get_project_root() -> Path:
    """Returns project root folder."""
    return Path(__file__).parent.parent

    return get_project_root().joinpath(path)
```

Then simply call the function with the **file_path** as an argument:

```
filePath = get_file('com/python/example/source/utils/configManager.py')
```

And then the usual procedure:

```
while open(filePath) as f:
    <DO YOUR THING>
```