# python search path for data files (non-modules) - text files (*txt)

Tags: python

Base on http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/searchPath.html

**Search Path (sys.path)**

```
A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules. Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an installation-dependent default.
```

Its a path to search for *modules* in import statements.

I am wondering which path is used for search for data files (*txt files etc). For eg. If I do a fs.open(someFile), which all paths python will search for it?

Is it sys.path itself or ?

My confusion is that the docs say sys.path is a search path for **modules** and data files are `not` modules.

Comment: related: [Python : How to access file from different directory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17244406/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such option. Only the current working directory is searched if no path is specified in the filename.

Comment: holy cow I had to read that a few times to understand what he was asking... nice work(+1)

Answer (score 1):

As Ignacio says, there is no built in variable for this.  Either the user or the script itself must supply the directory or directories to search for files.

`python script.py /path/to/file/file_to_parse`

And our script:

```
#script.py

import sys
my_file = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')

#act on file
```