# Path Changed in Python Script Executed by Another Python Script

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

A script at `/foo/bar.py` tries to run a second script `/main.py` using the `subprocess` module. Although `main.py` runs fine with `python main.py` in the Windows command prompt, running `bar.py` which calls `main.py` causes an error

```
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'user'
```

Why is there now a problem with the path to `settings.ini`, and how can we fix it?

**~/settings.ini**

```
[user]
id: helloworld
```

**~/foo/bar.py**

```
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "../main.py"])
```

**~/main.py**

```
Config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
Config.read("settings.ini")
userId = Config.get('user', 'id')
```

Comment: Is the current directory the same in each case?  I ask because the filename `settings.ini` is not qualified with a directory name, so you might be picking-up two different files.

Comment: it is more flexible to import the module and use its functions, classes directly instead of running it as a subprocess. See [Call python script with input with in a python script using subprocess](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30076185/4279)

Answer (score 1):

If `settings.ini` is presumed to be in the same directory as `main.py` you can deduce its full path from `__file__`  and read the settings using the full path.

**main.py**:

```
import os
ini_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "settings.ini")
Config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
Config.read(ini_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the `read()` method returns a non-empty list otherwise it means that `settings.ini` is not found. Relative paths are resolved relative to the current working directory (place where you've run `python`), not  script's directory (where `bar.py` is stored).

You should probably use [`appdirs.user_config_dir()`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/appdirs), to get the directory where to put user's configuration files. Different OSes such as Windows, macOS, Linux distributions may use different defaults. `appdirs` follows conventions that are appropriate for a given OS.

If you want to get data stored in a file that is packaged with your installed Python modules then you could use [`pkgutil.get_data()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data) or setuptools' [`pkg_resources.resource_string()`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#resourcemanager-api) that [work even if your package is inside an archive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5355694/4279). It is not recommended to construct the paths manually but if you need the directory with the current script then you could [put `get_script_dir()` function into your script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22881871/4279)—it is more general than `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`. If the relative position is always the same then you could use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess
import sys

main_script_dir = os.path.join(get_script_dir(), os.pardir)
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'main'], cwd=main_script_dir)
```

See [Python : How to access file from different directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17244406/4279)