# Best way to specify path of file for different uses without having to write a custom path for each one

Tags: python, pytest

I have a file (`dataset.json`) that needs to be accessed from different places (tests.py, relative imports, and actual uses). I currently have a file structure similar to this:

```
project_dir
    |
    + - module_1
        |
        + - __init__.py
        + - abcd.py
        + - dataset.json
    + - xyz.py
    + - tests
        |
        + - tests_abcd.py
```

The issue that I'm trying to resolve is being able to read `dataset.json` from `abcd.py`. When I import `abcd.py` from `xyz.py` or `tests_abcd.py`, I get a `FileNotFoundError` because the path is different.

I've gone over the different methods for reading that file from this [article](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f), but it doesn't necessarily solve my problems. I also looked into this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder) as well. This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56782620/5799075) was helpful, but it didn't completely solve the problem.

What's the best way to define the file path? I don't want to write 50 different ways to access this file for each use case, and I wanted to learn what's the best way to handle problems like this.

Comment: at every folder level create an empty __init__.py file, now you can trying importing like from project_dir.module_1.dataset.json

Comment: That won't work because running `python xyz.py` would cause abcd to search in `project_dir` instead of module_1

Answer (score 0):

Inside `abcd.py`:

```
from pathlib import Path
import json


def read_data():
    with open(Path(__file__).parent / 'dataset.json') as f:
        return json.load(f)
```

From `xyz.py`:

```
from module_1.abcd import read_data

my_data = read_data()
```

Or something along those lines, of course you don't have to return the data, you can just use it inside `abcd.py`.

`__file__` is local to the script evaluating it, so `xyz.py` gets its own path and you can open the .json sitting next to it by prefixing the filename with the same parent path.

Comment: Going to go to sleep, I'll look into this in the morning. It's 3AM here :p